# Highchart for Android library x-range chart How to use dynamic y-axis data

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, highcharts, xrange

While using the x-range high chart library, the x-axis contains date information data for each part, and the y-axis contains the title of each part. The y-axis contains a different number of titles per account rather than a fixed number. On the web, you can process it as an Arraylist, but in the Android example, you need to put one Map for each y-axis line, how should you handle it?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the following demo code: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/android/x-range and this article https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-android-wrapper-tutorial/ where you will find examples of categories implementation. Let me know if that helped you!

Comment: Thank you for answer. But this is not the answer I am looking for. I have already referenced this tutorial, and in that tutorial, I saw that the y-axis value is fixed.
One value on the x-axis is entered for each y-axis. However, the value of the X-axis is in the form of a Hashmap. Is there a way to change the format?

Comment: Unfortunately, the official demo shows the only proper way to achieve that and there is no option to use a different format than HashMap.

Comment: thank you.
It's a pity that I must use HashMap.